# SharePoint Online classic - all the CSS and JS files are being loaded twice, why?

Tags: sharepoint-online

See the developer dashboard network data. Please someone explain me why CSS and JS files are being loaded twice? how can I fix it? I believe it is slowing down the page load speed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There might be references of same files in following pages:

1. Master Page
2. Site Page

Comment: There is no other reference anywhere. Even in the out of the box SharePoint seattle masterpage I see core CSS file being rendered twice and I'm not able to find anything on any search engine why this is happeing.

Comment: @user3277651 Try removing the references wherever it is present and add it again.